# Logo and Logo name are stacking instead of being side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On my website, I have a logo image and then company name. Currently it's stacked, so it's the logo image and below that is the company name.

What I want is for them to be side by side. So on the left side would be the logo image and then to the right of it would be the company name.

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-fixed-top">
  <header>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #CFE4F1">
     <div class="container-fluid">
       <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home" style="color:"><img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/698660793265446912/cAMrktol.png" alt="A Super Maid Logo"> COMPANY NAME</a>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need some CSS to make this happen.

I wrapped your site name with a span, since you already had the image inside of the link for your site branding.

```
.navbar-brand img, .navbar-brand span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Using this method you can easily align the logo to the top, bottom, baseline, etc.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/karolbrennan/qjuqgke1/

An alternative method is simply to float the logo to the left:

```
.navbar-brand img {
  float: left;
}
.navbar-brand {
  clear: both;
}
```

Note that I cleared the link so you won't have issues with the floats.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/karolbrennan/pny02qcm/1/

Comment: It works in your fiddle, but it doesn't work on my website.

Comment: Can you send me a link and I can take a look for ya? You might have some CSS overriding it.